# PHP/Oracle: CLOB binding variable error with large file

Tags: php, oracle, binding, procedure

I'm binding a string variable(`$xml`) in PHP which is part of a call to a procedure in Oracle 12c, now the data for the `CLOB` is quite big, is there an easy way to fix this?

I've checked the upload with a much smaller file and it all works fine, the problem just occurs with large files.

I've tried `XMLTYPE` and `RAW` in place of `CLOB` but neither seemed to work.

**PHP**

```
public function uploadXml($xml, $fileName)
{
    $query = 'BEGIN XML_PKG.PR_LOAD_XML_FILE (
        i_XML_DOC => :i_XML_DOC,
        i_FILENAME => :i_FILENAME
        );
    END;';

    $stmt = $this->connection->prepare($query);

    $bindVars = array('i_XML_DOC' => $xml
        , 'i_FILENAME' => $fileName
    );

    $stmt->execute($bindVars);
}
```

**SQL**

```
PROCEDURE PR_LOAD_XML_FILE (
    i_XML_DOC IN CLOB,
    i_FILENAME IN XML_DOCS.FILENAME%TYPE
);
```

**Error**

```
ORA-01460: unimplemented or unreasonable conversion requested
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a descriptor

```
$descriptor = oci_new_descriptor($db->getConnection(), OCI_DTYPE_LOB);
$descriptor->writetemporary($xml, OCI_TEMP_CLOB);
$stmt->bindParam(':V_XML', $descriptor, OCI_B_CLOB, -1);
```